# Arduino UNO UART coding in pure C

Tags: arduino-uno, c, uart

Below is a simple `USART` code for `ARDUINO` written in `Pure C`.
But due to uknown(in reference to me) reasons, the code is not provicing desired output.

Can someone point out the error in the code.
I cannot use the `Arduino` built in function `Serial.begin` as i need to use USART receive `interrupts`.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000
#define BAUD 9600 
#include<util/setbaud.h>

void UART_Init();

void setup() 
{
    UART_Init();
}

void loop()
{
    UART_Transmit('c');
}

void UART_Init()
{
   UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
   UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE; 
   UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<TXEN0);
   UCSR0C = (3<<UCSZ00);
}

void UART_Transmit(unsigned char data)
{
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = data;
}
```

Comment: Compiled as an Arduino sketch, your code runs like a charm on my Uno. How did you compile it?

Comment: @EdgarBonet I did compiled it on Arduino IDE . There was no error in the code. But after uploading to the board the `output` received is not as expected.

Comment: What kind of output did you expect? I see a long stream of "ccccccccccccccccccccccc...", and that's what I expect from reading the code.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I too expect that only. But am not getting it.In my serial monitor, I get only `square boxes`

Comment: At 115200 baud rate, the correct output is received. But for 9600, the output is square boxes.

Comment: Is this a real Uno clocked at 16 MHz? Could you post the generated elf somewhere?

Comment: @EdgarBonet I am using an Arduino clone clocked at 16Mhz. `elf file`: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iixou908mjdcapk/chk041.ino.elf?dl=0)

Comment: I can't download that without opening a Dropbox account, which I won't do.

Comment: suggest a good alternative please.

Comment: @EdgarBonet [elf file](https://ufile.io/j1qcd)

Comment: i am stuck in the same problem...not able to use arduino serial functions .....while using uart receive interrupt.....
have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

The `UBRR0` calculation was the mistake

For making the code work for baud rate 9600, we need to set the equation as:

> UBRR0 = (F_CPU / 4 / baud - 1) / 2;

and also double the USART speed by setting :

> UCSR0A = (1<< U2X0)

I hope someone will find this information helpful.

Comment: `util/setbaud.h` defines `USE_2X` to 0 or 1 depending on whether the `U2X` bit is needed. Then you can `UCSRA |= (USE_2X << U2X);`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks for the help man. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

> UBRR0 = (F_CPU / 4 / baud - 1) / 2;

you probably want to check the datasheet for that.

One way to code it is to change it based on the U2X bit, like this:

```
UxBRR=F_UART / ((UxCSRA & (1<<U2X0))?8:16) / baud - 1;          //generate baud rate register
```

So the user can change the U2X bit freely and the software will take care of it.

there is one set of uart polling and interrupt-driven routines that I use: https://github.com/dannyf00/My-MCU-Library/tree/master/UART/UARTISR/ATMega328p

they have the same user interface so can be exchanged freely.